# Minimal BASH-like supported... after installing Debian. How to proceed now?

Tags: debian, debian-installer, debian-cd

I just installed Debian Stretch from a live USB. I left the installation do all the partition and such automatically. But I reboot to a black screen that says:

> Minimal BASH-like line editing is supported...

In which direction should I go now?

**EDIT:**

I can boot every time if I type this cryptic arcane I blindly copied from a forum:

> set root=(hd0,gpt2)
>
> linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/sda2 ro
>
> initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
>
> boot

How can I do those changes permanent? I'm almost there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Somehow grub configuration of your system isn't made properly. You can either make the grub entries manually or use `grub2-mkconfig` tool to make it for you.

Find for the file named `grub.cfg` in `/boot` probably it'll be in `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

If you want to do it manually make the following entey in the file.

```
menuentry 'Debian' {
set root=(hd0,gpt2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz-3.16.0-4-amd64 root=/dev/sda2 ro         
initrd /boot/initrd.img-3.16.0-4-amd64
}
```

Or you can install `grub2-mkconfig` as follows once after booting the system manually. **(Recommended)**

```
sudo apt install grub2-tools
```

Make a backup of your existing `grub.cfg`

```
cp /boot/grub/grub.cfg /boot/grub/grub.cfg.back
```

Then generat new `grub.cfg` using `grub2-mkconfig` as follows

```
grub2-mkconfig >/boot/grub/grub.cfg
```

Now your system shall boot normally

**Note** I've assumed location of `grub.cfg` in your system is `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`. If you find a different location please use that location.