# Debian dualboot (WIN10) - can't install GRUB boot loader

Tags: debian, dual-boot

I wanted to give a try to Linux again. So I decided to install Debian next to my Win 10. I prepared harddrives in Win 10:

**Disc 1 (SSD 850 EVO [u]250[/u]GB):**

One partition - Win 10

**Disc 2 (SSD 850 EVO [u]500[/u]GB):**

Two partitions with some data

Third partition for debian install

Fourth partition for swap

After some trouble with my flashdisk I finally get to installation.  Debian is now installed on 3. partitions, but during the installation, GRUB bootloader failed:

```
Executing 'grub-install dummy' failed
```

So I skip this step and after finishing install I reboot my PC. After reboot, Win 10 loaded correctly. After next reboot I hit F11 for Boot device selection. Now I have here next to Win 10 also Debian:
[image: boot selection]

But when I selected debian, I will boot into this:
[image: after boot]
Now I guess I should have register debian partition into GRUB. But I don't know how, can you give me some advice? 
Thanks a lot

Comment: Have you tried https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423163/minimal-bash-like-supported-after-installing-debian-how-to-proceed-now/423170#423170 ? Please replace hard disk number, kernal, initrd and grub.cfg properly.

Comment: An easy automated way (suggested for beginners) is to use bootrepairdisk (https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/)... You have just to burn it in a cd or a usb and boot from this... It will ask you if you want to apply a recommended repair and it will do what needed to repair your boot options and entries...

Comment: @AbhikBose Thanks for advice. Now I can boot into Debian with commands in the linked question. But after i wrote them into grub.cfg (i have to created it), it will show me the GRUB OS selection window, but after i choose debian, it will give me erorr about `initrd not found`, `you need to load kernel first`

Comment: @Sk1X1 I believe it's due to some configuration error. Please use `grub2-mkconfig` tool to generate `grub.cfg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end, it was configruration error. I run `update-grub` and that created confiuration file `grub-conf` with right configuration.